# Create an array in TikZ with \underbrace in different colors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create TikZ something like:

```
-------------------------------  ...   ----------------
| 0000 | 0001 | 0010 | 0100 |           | 0111 | 1111 |
------------------------------  ...   -----------------
\     / \                  /                    \     /
 \M_0/   \------ M_1------/                      \M_d/
```

where I could give the first box one color, the 3 box after words different color and the last one a 3rd color.

I tried to create `\underbrace` for the `M_0`, `M_1` and `M_d`

Does someone know where I could find short example for something like this?

**EDIT**

Thank you for the nice solutions. In my example above it was hard to see and also to create an example for it, so below is an example how i would like to have the connecting box. I hope it is also possible a relative easy way.

[image]

Comment: You could have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31336/how-can-i-display-an-array-as-in-the-data-structure-from-computer-science-not. It should be straightforward to add some color in TikZ. Just use the `color=colorname` option.

Comment: If the above link solves your question, we should close this one. If it doesn't, please make clear how it doesn't.

Comment: Answers in the link are (too) complex for this kind of problem but it's a personal point of view.

Comment: @Seamus, this solution is in the direction of what i am searching for, but not exactly. Please see the edit part.

Comment: @Eagle: I've updated my answer to include dashed lines - slightly crude, but since I had something sans-`tikz` originally, I stuck to it. `:)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This solution builds on Altermundus answer; I only used the `shapes` library to add two "tapes"  to get the desired aspect for the interrupted band:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \c/\i [count=\n] in  
        {blue!20/0001,red!20/0001,red!20/0010,red!20/0100} 
           \node[draw,fill=\c,minimum height=1cm,minimum width = 2cm,xshift=\n*2cm,font=\ttfamily](N\n){\i} ;

  \draw [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] (N1.south west) --  node[below=10pt]{$M_0$}(N1.south east); 
  \draw [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] (N1.south east) --  node[below=10pt]{$M_1$}(N4.south east);

  \node [tape, draw,minimum size=1cm,tape bend top=none,
tape bend height=0.4cm,rotate=90] at (9.3,0) (t) {};
  \node [tape, draw,minimum size=1cm,tape bend top=none,
tape bend height=0.4cm,rotate=270] at (11.3,0) (t) {};

\node at (10.3,0.5) {\dots};
\node at (10.3,-0.5) {\dots};

\foreach \c/\i [count=\m] in  
        {olive!20/0111,green!20/1111} 
           \node[draw,fill=\c,minimum height=1cm,minimum width = 2cm,xshift=10.6cm+\m*2cm](N\m){\i} ;
  \draw [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] (N2.south west) --  node[below=10pt]{$M_d$}(N2.south east); 

 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \c/\i [count=\n] in  
        {blue!20/0001,red!20/0001,red!20/0010,red!20/0100,white/\dots,yellow!20/0100} 
           \node[draw,fill=\c,minimum height=1cm,minimum width = 2cm,xshift=\n*2cm](N\n){\i} ;

 \draw [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] (N1.south west) --  node[below=10pt]{$M_0$}(N1.south east); 
 \draw [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] (N1.south east) --  node[below=10pt]{$M_1$}(N4.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update :** Gonzalo was faster than me ! My code below is not complete I stop it when I saw the good answer of Gonzalo. I put my idea because I find a great difficulty. In my idea the connecting boxes contained numbers. here the result :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[tape, draw,fill=red!20, tape bend top=none,rotate=90,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=2cm] at (7.92, 0) {};  
  \node[tape, draw,fill=yellow!20, tape bend bottom=none,rotate=90,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=2cm] at (12, 0) {};   
 \foreach \c/\i/\b [count=\n] in  
        {blue!20/0001/1,red!20/0001/1,red!20/0010/1,/0100/0,//0,/0100/0} 
{\ifnum \b=1
  \node[draw,fill=\c,minimum height=1cm,minimum width = 2cm,xshift=\n*2cm](N\n){\i} ;
  \else  
    \node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width = 2cm,xshift=\n*2cm](N\n){\i} ;  
  \fi }

 \draw [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] (N1.south west) --  node[below=10pt]{$M_0$}(N1.south east); 
  \draw [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] (N1.south east) --  node[below=10pt]{$M_1$}(N4.south east); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The difficulty is real !   because I can't rotate nodes with numbers inside.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Another option without using [`tikz/pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newcommand{\cbox}[2]{%
  \fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\texttt{#2\strut}}\kern-\fboxrule}% Coloured box
\begin{document}
\[
  \savebox{\tempbox}{\cbox{white}{~~~~~~}}
  \underbrace{\cbox{red!30}{0000}}_{M_0}\!
  \underbrace{\cbox{green!20}{0001}
    \cbox{green!20}{0010}
    \cbox{green!20}{0100}}_{M_1}\!
  \rlap{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
  \makebox[\wd\tempbox][c]{%
    \fcolorbox{white}{white}{$\!\strut\cdot\!$}~%
    \fcolorbox{white}{white}{$\!\strut\cdot\!$}~%
    \fcolorbox{white}{white}{$\!\strut\cdot\!$}}\!
  \cbox{white}{0111}\!
  \underbrace{\cbox{blue!40}{1111}}_{M_d}
\]
\end{document}​
```

The macro `\cbox{<color>}{<stuff>}` typesets `<stuff>` in the appropriate (framed) `\fcolorbox` with colour `<color>`. Modifying the frame colour to `white` and overlaying it on the enlarged rectangle multiple times (slightly spaced) provides the faux dashed line style to "break" the sequence.

Comment: hehe... I was just about to post a similar TikZ-free solution.

Comment: a bit shorter: `\newcommand\cbox[2]{\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\texttt{#2\strut}}\kern-\fboxrule}`

Answer (score 5):

You can create the wiggly lines manually using Bezier curves,
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\WigglyStrength{2/3}
    % Left box
    \draw
        (0,0)
        -- ++(2,0)
        .. controls +(\WigglyStrength,1/3) and +(-\WigglyStrength,-1/3) .. ++(0,1)
        -- ++(-2,0)
        ;
    % Right box
    \draw
        (6,0)
        -- ++(-2,0)
        .. controls +(\WigglyStrength,1/3) and +(-\WigglyStrength,-1/3) .. ++(0,1)
        -- ++(2,0)
        ;
    % Dashed lines
    \draw [dashed]
        (0,0) ++(2,0) -- ++(2,0)
        (0,1) ++(2,0) -- ++(2,0)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I often look for ways to create "byte array" or "square array" (or rather, "rectangle array") as vector graphics - and one way to do it in Tikz, is to use `rectangle split` shape. (It is also possible to do with the `D` symbol in the `tikz-timing` package, but I'll skip that here).

Below is the code using `rectangle split` that renders this:

[image: test31.png]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} %\widthof
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newlength\tmpl
\setlength{\tmpl}{\widthof{0000}} % \settowidth{\tmpl}{0000} gives 0.0
\typeout{\tmpl \the\tmpl} % \tmpl 20.00006pt
\tikzstyle{nn} = [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, text width=\tmpl, align=center]
\tikzstyle{db} = [decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate]

\coordinate[] (origin) at (0,0);

\node[
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split horizontal=true,
  rectangle split empty part width=\tmpl,
  rectangle split parts=7,
  %rectangle split use custom fill,%=true, % documented, but nowork tikz 1.5.1
  rectangle split part fill={blue!20,red!20,red!20,red!20,none,olive!20,green!20},
  line width=1pt,
  draw,
] (barr1) [above=5pt of origin]
{%
\nodepart[nn,fill=red!50]{one}0001% fill is ignored here!
\nodepart[nn]{two}0001%
\nodepart[nn]{three}0010%
\nodepart[nn]{four}0100%
\nodepart[nn]{five}...%
\nodepart[nn]{six}0100%
\nodepart[nn]{seven}1111%
};

\draw [db] (barr1.south west) -- node[below=10pt]{$M_0$} (barr1.one split south);
\draw [db] (barr1.one split south) -- node[below=10pt]{$M_1$} (barr1.four split south);
\draw [db] (barr1.six split south) -- node[below=10pt]{$M_d$} (barr1.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```