# How to draw array (data structure) and show partition?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm doing a homework for algorithm class where I have to show what a particular array looks like at each step of the quick sort algorithm, in a manner similar to this image: (page from CLRS book).

[image: array image]

I would like to know how to draw an array that looks like the one in the book. In particular, I want to know how to (in order from most to least important)

- Draw an array.
- Put letter(s) above a node or a blank space.
- Draw the black bars that partition the array.
- Customize a cell with gray or light gray color.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @Seamus: Before I asked the question, I found the following [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31336/how-can-i-display-an-array-as-in-the-data-structure-from-computer-science-not)
which shows me how to draw an array. Since I'm not familiar with using tikz, I'm unable to modify the code to include black bars, letter above a cell, or customized color (I can only modify the spacing). Note that typesetting this array is not necessary for the assignment, since I can draw it by hand. It just would be nice to know how to.

Comment: You can change the output. Take a look here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83727/pretty-lists-for-sorting-algorithms .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{W}{!{\smash{\vrule
\@width 4\arrayrulewidth
\@height\dimexpr\ht\@arstrutbox+2pt\relax
\@depth\dimexpr\dp\@arstrutbox+2pt\relax}}}
\makeatother
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{.7,.7,.7}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|cWc|cWc|cWc|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$p$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$i$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$j$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$}\\
\cellcolor{gray}2&
\cellcolor{gray}1&
\cellcolor{gray}3&
\cellcolor{black}&
\cellcolor{black}&
5&
6&
4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Your code is straightforward and easy to understand, too. :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But, but... that's not TikZ! No fair!